# Change FreePBX Queue settings programatically?

Tags: asterisk, queue, freepbx

Is there is anyway to change the settings(such as 'timeout') of a queue added by FreePBX?. I found No such options in Asterisk Manager (AMI) and CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Actualy, no. Because FreePBX keeps queue configs in files.

But you can use Realtime Queues http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+RealTime+Queue and change settings through database.